# Как выбрать дочерний элемент используя jquery?

Tags: jquery

Есть много div-ов с классом `info`.
В каждом div-е есть по одному checkbox-у с классом `chkbx`.

Хочу пробежаться по всем checkbox-ам, но не получается:

```
$('.info').each(function(){
  alert($(this).('.chkbx').attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: `$(this).('.chkbx')` - не опечатка? Правильный вариант -  `$(this).find('.chkbx')`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибка. Нужно так:

```
$('.info .chkbx').each(function(){
  alert($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

или

```
$('.info').each(function(){
  alert($(this).find('.chkbx').prop('checked'));
});
```